# How to modify enumerate label format for right to left list in context

Tags: enumerate, context, right-to-left

I would like to use `context` to write right to left list, `\textdir TRT` and  `\pardir TRT` managed to write right to left text.

In case of list, if we use `\startitemize[n]`  labels looks like this

[image]

The above image is the result of this MWE

```
\starttext
\textdir TRT
\pardir TRT
Hello world

\startitemize[n]
\item  text 1
\item  text 2
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

My question is how to obtain labels look like `.1` and `.2` or otherwise how can we change the format of list label in context, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the direction of your text with the `righttoleft` (or `r2l`) keyword for the `\setupalign` command. The use of `\textdir` and `\pardir` is not recommended because ConTeXt sets a flag when you use the `\setupalign` command to set the direction which is needed by some environments.

```
\setupalign[righttoleft]

\starttext

Hello world

\startitemize[n]
\item text 1
\item text 2
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image: Global change of the text direction]

You can also change the direction of the text for a part of your document with the `alignment` environment. The command takes the arguments as `\setupalign`.

```
\starttext

\startitemize[n]
\item  text 1
\item  text 2
\stopitemize

\startalignment[righttoleft]
    \startitemize[n]
    \item  text 1
    \item  text 2
    \stopitemize
\stopalignment

\stoptext
```

[image: Local change of the text direction]

Comment: Thanks @Metafox, can I modify text direction in the same document?

Comment: @salimbou I extended my answer with a example for a local change of the text direction.